# req.body is not updating using <form>

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

First time writing REST API's for a CRUD, and stuck on this problem. 
req.body is not updating when I use the edit form below. All previous data is intact. It displays correctly in the form and console. But no changes using the edit form get passed with the body.

```
//EDIT ROUTE
app.get("/list/:id/edit", function(req, res){
    Order.findById(req.params.id, function(err, foundOrder){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.render("edit", {order:foundOrder});
        }
    });
});

//UPDATE ROUTE
app.put("/list/:id", function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.order);
    Order.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body.order, function(err, updatedOrder){
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
        else{
            res.redirect("/list/" +req.params.id);    
        }
    });
});

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//edit.ejs
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

<form class="form-group" id="usrform" action="/list/<%= order._id %>?_method=PUT" method="POST">


        <p><textarea name="location" cols="50" rows="3" ><%= order.location %></textarea></p>


        <p><textarea name="time" cols="50" rows="3"><%= order.time %></textarea></p>


        <p><textarea name="desc" cols="50" rows="7"><%= order.desc %></textarea></p>

        <button class="orderButton">Submit</button>

  </form>
```

Comment: You seem to be referencing an `order` property of `body`, but there's no such value being passed by your form submit.

Comment: But it is being passed. Just not updated. It is not undefined.
However, i solved it by changing the name value to point to the order object (or db or whatever it is)